# How can I create dynamic menus and pages driven from database?

Tags: php, mysql, loops, dynamic, menu

I am a newbie here and for php too. I am not new to stackoverflow though :)

I am creating a simple reporting system and I want the menues and pages to be generated from the database.

I saw [this video on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zlAchewKJ7k) and managed to create a menu with the following code.

I have a database table called `Reports` and columns called `rep_id`, `rep_date`, `rep_ledit_date`, `rep_by`, `department`, `position`, `report`, and `rep_to`.

So based on the above method, I created a menu using this code.

```
<?php 

require ("includes/db.php");

mysqli_select_db($con, '$db_name');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM reports";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die (mysqli_error($con));
$represult=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$rep_by=$represult['rep_by'];
$report=$represult['report']; 

?>  
<li> Menu
<ul>
<?php do 
       {
?>
<li><a href="reports.php?rep_id=<?php echo $represult['rep_id']; ?>"> <?php echo $represult['rep_by'] . " (" .   $represult['rep_date'] . ")"; ?></a></li>

<?php 
     } while ($represult=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result));
    //$represult['rep_by'];
    //$represult['report'];
    //$represult['report'] ;
?>
</ul>
</li>
```

So I created a page called `reports.php` to see the details of the content in the database. What I wanted was to see the following **rep_by (rep_date)** as a heading and report as a content.

I might want to use other columns in the content too. So what kind of code the menu and `reports.php` should have to achieve what I want. What I did was the following and it only outputs the first row when all the menu links are clicked.

```
 require ("includes/db.php");

 mysqli_select_db($con, '$db_name');

 $sql= "SELECT * FROM reports";
 $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die (mysqli_error($con));
 $represult=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); 

 <h1> <?php echo $represult['rep_by'] . " (" . $represult['rep_date'] . ")"; ?></a></h1>
 <?php echo $represult['report']; ?>
```

Comment: It looks like you provided the PHP code for menu.php. Are you asking for an example of the PHP code for reports.php?

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles, I modified it now. The error was made when posting on this forum. The problem is still there on reports.php

Comment: The explanation is much clearer. You provided the PHP code for reports.php (plural). However your "<li><a href" is also linked to reports.php (plural). I bet you meant to link it to report.php (singular).

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles, good observation. That is again my bad in writing it on this forum. I will fix it. My problem is, the pages doesn't show their corresponding report, rather just the first row from the database.

Comment: Yes, the "WHERE rep_id = ?" part of the query was missing. See the provided report.php example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

report.php:

```
<?php

require ('includes/db.php');

mysqli_select_db($con, $db_name);

$sql= 'SELECT * FROM Reports WHERE rep_id = ?';
$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
$id = $_GET['rep_id'];
$stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
$stmt->execute();

$stmt->bind_result($rep_id, $rep_date, $rep_ledit_date, $rep_by, $department, $position, $report, $rep_to);
$stmt->fetch();

?>

<h1><?php echo "$rep_by ($rep_date)"; ?></h1>
<?php echo $report; ?>
```

reports.php (tweaked a bit)

```
<?php 

require ('includes/db.php');

mysqli_select_db($con, $db_name);

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM Reports';
$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();

$stmt->bind_result($rep_id, $rep_date, $rep_ledit_date, $rep_by, $department, $position, $report, $rep_to);

?>  
Menu
<ul>
<?php while ($stmt->fetch()) { ?>

<li><a href="report.php?rep_id=<?php echo $rep_id; ?>"> <?php echo "$rep_by ($rep_date)"; ?></a></li>

<?php } ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: @ bloodyKnuckles, Thank you so much. Your solution works perfectly well. You made my day! Now I have to learn about bind_param, bind_result, and their friends as my project will have a lot of them. Where could I find a good info on them?

Comment: @ bloodyKnuckles, how are you doing. I have new issue related to the solution you gave me last time. Would you help me on this please. Than you! http://stackoverflow.com/a/23961453/3674573

Comment: @ bloodyKnuckles, I am facing a new problem now. I get the following error Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in /home/wt/public_html/view-reports.php on line 237 . It is the same message for the tweaked report.php - which is now view-reports.php. I also see another problem. The variables generated doesn't echo the right corresponding data. For instance, $rep_type echo position. Could you please help me on this. Thank you! Test site url is here. http://ethioserver.com/~wt/view-reports.php?rep_id=144

Comment: Post a new question with the view-reports.php code, particularly around line 237 and in relation to the $stmt variable that you're using to call execute. Somehow the $stmt variable is not getting made into a database object, hence the error, calling execute on a non-object.

Comment: Ok thank you! I have posted a new question here. http://stackoverflow.com/q/24086070/3674573