# Update MySQL record on a page created with GET url ID

Tags: php, mysql, url, select, get

I am creating a simple reporting system and I want the menues and pages to be generated from the database.

I saw this video on YouTube and managed to create a menu with the following code.

I have a database table called Reports and columns called rep_id, rep_date, rep_ledit_date, rep_by, department, position, report, and rep_to. And another table called users with columns called id, username, password, first_name, last_name, department, postion, and passphrase.

I managed to select the an added record for the reports table, however, I have the following problems. 
1. The rep_to doesn't preselect the already chosen option
2. The record cannot be updated with php  Notice: Undefined index: rep_id in C:\wamp\www\cme\edit-this-report.php on line 232 and no update on the database. This line is where report table is selected
Please see the php code below.

```
<?php
  if(isset($_SESSION['users'])) { 
      $uname = $_SESSION['users']; 
      $fname = $_SESSION['firstname'];
      $lname = $_SESSION['lastname'];
      $dep = $_SESSION['depart'];
      $pos = $_SESSION['position'];
      $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = $uname");
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
          $id=$row['id'];
          $fname=$row['first_name']; 
          $lname=$row['last_name'];
          $dep = $row['department']; 
          $pos = $row['position']; 
          $repby = $row['first_name'] . " " . $row['last_name']; 
          $repdep = $row['department'];
          $reppos = $row['position'];
      } 
   } 

        mysqli_select_db($con, $db_name);
        $edit= "SELECT * FROM reports WHERE rep_id = '{$_GET['rep_id']}'";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $edit) or die(mysqli_error($con));

        $row2 =  mysqli_fetch_array($result);

  if(isset($_POST['update'])) {
      $_GET['rep_id']=$row2['rep_id'];
      $reptype = $_POST['reporttype'];
      $report = $_POST['report'];
      $repto = $_POST['reportedto'];
      $update=(mysqli_select_db($con, $db_name));
      if(!$update) {
          die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error($con));
      }
      else {
          $sql = "UPDATE reports SET rep_type='$reptype', report='$report', rep_to='$repto',
                  rep_ledit_date=NOW() WHERE rep_id='{$_GET['rep_id']}'";
          $retval = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
          if(!$retval ) {
              $errorMessage='Could not update data: ' . mysqli_error($con);
          }
          else {
              $success="Updated data successfully\n";
              header("location:edit-this-report.php"); 
              mysqli_close($con);
          }
      }
  }

?>
```

And the form code:

```
  <form name="editor" action="edit-this-report.php" method="post" >
   <p class="inline">
    <span>
       <label for="mem">Reported by</label>
  <input type="text" name="reportedby" maxlength="20" disabled value="<?php print  $fname . " " . $lname; ?>" />
    </span>
   </p>
   <p class="inline">
     <span>
        <label for="mem">Department Name</label><input type="text" name="repdepart" disabled size="100" maxlength="100" value="<?php print $dep; ?>">
     </span>
   </p>

   <p class="inline">
      <span>
        <label for="mem">Position</label><input disabled type="text" name="repposition" size="100" value="<?php print $pos; ?>">
      </span>
   </p>

   <p>
     <span>
      <label for="mem">Report Type</label> 
       <select name="reporttype">
          <option value=""<?php if ($row2['rep_type'] === 'Daily Report') echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>Daily Report</option>
          <option  value=""<?php if ($row2['rep_type'] === 'Weekly Report') echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>Weekly Report</option>
          <option value=""<?php if ($row2['rep_type'] === 'Monthly Report') echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>Monthly Report</option>
          <option value=""<?php if ($row2['rep_type'] === 'Quarterly Report') echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>Quarterly Report</option>
          <option value=""<?php if ($row2['rep_type'] === 'Annual Report') echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>Annual Report</option>
          <option  value=""<?php if ($row2['rep_type'] === 'Terminal Report') echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>Terminal Report</option>
      </select>
     <span>
   </p>

   <p>
    <span>
         <label for="mem">Report</label> 
         <textarea name="report" id="report" rows="23" cols="auto" ><?php echo $row2['report'];?></textarea>
    <span>
   </p>
   <p>
    <span>
        <label for="mem">Reported to</label> 
        <select name="reportedto">
  <?php
  require ("includes/db.php");
        $q2= "SELECT * FROM users WHERE department like '%$repdep%'"; 
        $result3=mysqli_query($con, $q2) or die(mysqli_error($con));
        while ($getuser=mysqli_fetch_array($result3)){
        $repto=$getuser['first_name'] . " " . $getuser['last_name'];
  ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $repto; ?>"><?php echo $repto; ?></option>; 
        <?php       
        }       
        ?>

        </select>

    </span>
   </p>
    <span>
        <input name="update" type="submit" class="btn btn-large btn-primary" id="report_button" value="Submit Report" > 
        <input name="cancel" type="reset" class="btn btn-large btn-secondary" id="report_button" value="Cancel All Changes" >
    </span>
   </p>
  </form>
```

Please help me on this.

Thanks!

Comment: I guess you'll need to create a `name="rep_id"` somewhere ;-)

Comment: `session_start();` is loaded right? *Ah, knew it*.

Comment: BTW, the great advantage of this API over the old one is the introduction of prepared statements. Check them out!

Comment: @Fred-ii, what is the use of name="rep_id"? Yes, I have started session in the first few line.

Comment: @Strawberry, do you know any webpage that talks about them well?

Comment: Far as I know `Notice: Undefined index: xxx` is an error which is related to a form-related issue.

Comment: @Fredi-ii-, the problem with that is, there is no form field for ID. It is drawn from the GET url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a `rep_id` variable set in your form, so you're not getting back that value when submitting the form. You're relying on $_GET['rep_id'] in the previous query to provide the rep_id for your UPDATE, but I see no $_GET vars provided in your form. (Maybe not best practice to mix POST and GET, better yet add a hidden form var and set it to `rep_id`, and capture that as a POST var.)

None the less, the easiest way I can think of to make your code work is to append the rep_id to the form action attribute:

```
<form name="editor" action="edit-this-report.php?rep_id=<?php echo $_GET['rep_id']; ?>" method="post" >
```

Run that and report back if you get any more errors.

Another problem, though maybe not a show-stopper, before that in the `SELECT * FROM users` query, the $uname var is not quoted. Bigger, future problem though is using insecure, user-provided or hacker-manipulable variables in your SQL statements leaves your database open to sql-injection attacks.

UPDATE:

Consider something like this:

```
<?php

session_start();

require ('includes/db.php'); // provides $con, select database

// get logon info
if ( !isset($_SESSION['username']) ) { header('Location: logon.php'); } // logon and set session vars
else {
  list($uname, $repby, $dep, $pos) = 
      array($_SESSION['username'], $_SESSION['repby'], $_SESSION['department'], $_SESSION['position']);
}

// get report id if GET'd
if ( isset($_GET['rep_id'])  ) {
    $rep_id = $_GET['rep_id'];
}

// update report if POST'd
else if ( isset($_POST['update'] ) ) {
    $rep_id  = $_POST['rep_id'];
    $reptype = $_POST['reporttype'];
    $report  = $_POST['report'];
    $repto   = $_POST['reportedto'];

    if ( mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, 'UPDATE reports SET rep_type= ?, report= ?, rep_to= ?, rep_ledit_date= ? WHERE rep_id= ?') ) {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sssi', $reptype, $report, $repto, NOW(), $rep_id);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }
    else { $errorMessage='Could not update report data: ' . mysqli_error($con); }
}
else { die('no report id'); }

// get/verify report info (can be moved to get'd if to save a db call when post'd)
list($rep_type, $report) = array('', '');
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($con);
if ( mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, 'SELECT rep_id, rep_type, report FROM Reports WHERE rep_id = ?') ) {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'i', $rep_id);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $rep_id, $rep_type, $report);
    mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
else { $errorMessage='Could not select report data: ' . mysqli_error($con); }

?>


 <form name="editor" action="edit-this-report.php" method="post" >
   <input type="hidden" name="rep_id" value="<?=$rep_id?>">
   <p class="inline">
    <span>
       <label for="mem">Reported by</label>
  <input type="text" name="reportedby" maxlength="20" disabled value="<?=$repby?>" />
    </span>
   </p>
   <p class="inline">
     <span>
        <label for="mem">Department Name</label><input type="text" name="repdepart" disabled size="100" maxlength="100" value="<?=$dep?>">
     </span>
   </p>

   <p class="inline">
      <span>
        <label for="mem">Position</label><input disabled type="text" name="repposition" size="100" value="<?=$pos?>">
      </span>
   </p>

   <p>
     <span>
      <label for="mem">Report Type</label> 
       <select name="reporttype">

<?php

list($rep_type_da, $rep_type_we, $rep_type_mo, $rep_type_qu, $rep_type_an, $rep_type_te) = array('', '', '', '', '', '');
switch ( $rep_type ) {
    case 'Daily Report': $rep_type_da = ' selected'; break;
    case 'Daily Report': $rep_type_we = ' selected'; break;
    case 'Daily Report': $rep_type_mo = ' selected'; break;
    case 'Daily Report': $rep_type_qu = ' selected'; break;
    case 'Daily Report': $rep_type_an = ' selected'; break;
    case 'Daily Report': $rep_type_te = ' selected'; break;
}

?>
          <option value="Daily Report"    <?=$rep_type_da?>>Daily Report</option>
          <option value="Weekly Report"   <?=$rep_type_we?>>Weekly Report</option>
          <option value="Monthly Report"  <?=$rep_type_mo?>>Monthly Report</option>
          <option value="Quarterly Report"<?=$rep_type_qu?>>Quarterly Report</option>
          <option value="Annual Report"   <?=$rep_type_an?>>Annual Report</option>
          <option value="Terminal Report" <?=$rep_type_te?>>Terminal Report</option>
      </select>
     <span>
   </p>

   <p>
    <span>
         <label for="mem">Report</label> 
         <textarea name="report" id="report" rows="23" cols="auto" ><?=$report?></textarea>
    <span>
   </p>
   <p>
    <span>
        <label for="mem">Reported to</label> 
        <select name="reportedto">
          <option value=""></option>
<?php

if ( mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, 'SELECT CONCAT(first_name, last_name) AS repto FROM users WHERE department LIKE ?') ) {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', "%$dep%");
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $repto);
    while ( mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt) ) {
        echo '<option value="' . $repto . '">' . $repto . "</option>\n";
    }
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
else { $errorMessage='Could not select dep user data: ' . mysqli_error($con); }

?>

        </select>

    </span>
   </p>
    <span>
        <input name="update" type="submit" class="btn btn-large btn-primary" id="report_button" value="Submit Report" > 
        <input name="cancel" type="reset" class="btn btn-large btn-secondary" id="report_button" value="Cancel All Changes" >
    </span>
   </p>
  </form>
```

I've not set up the database so I've not tested it. If you run this and get errors, post them in the comments.

Comment: @ bloodyKnuckles, Thank you very much for the help. I did what you said and the error undefined rep_id is now gone but the changes is not being uploaded to the server. Thank you for the advice on sql injection. So putting quotes will help stop the injection?

Comment: Another problem I see is the value fields in the reporttype select options are empty. So no matter what is selected, the database would get updated with empty string.

Comment: Exactly, that is fixed now too.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to identify exactly which line above is line 232, but an "Undefined Index" error in PHP means that you have an array ($_GET and $_POST are both arrays) and you are trying to access a value (In this case, the one: $_GET['rep_id'] = 1;) but it can't find the 'index' in the array (in this case 'rep_id').

Somewhere you are accessing an array element via index that has not yet been defined on the page.

EDIT:
Probably here:
    $edit= "SELECT * FROM reports WHERE rep_id = '{$_GET['rep_id']}'";

$_GET is referencing a url variable called rep_id, but aren't you using post to send the rep_id? in this case try changing 
    $_GET['rep_id'] 
to 
    $_POST['rep_id']

Comment: @ Mark, Thank you for the help. I tried what you suggested and didn't work. The big problem is inability to edit the content. I made the menu linking the edit page based on this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23860556/how-can-i-create-dynamic-menus-and-pages-driven-from-database?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: Ah, I see now. You're looking for $_GET in case it is there. In that case, when I am writing PHP Code, I usually include an isset() call inside the IF statement, that way it doesn't throw an error/notice when it tires to find something that doesn't exist and clutter up the logs. In this case the error really means nothing, but you should still be developing with 0 notices or warnings for best practice.

Comment: That is right. It is now fixed with a hidden input field.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the solution given by bloodyKnuckles, I also got a help from a friend.
There is also a problem in giving initial values to the post values below  `if(isset($_POST['update']))`.

```
  <?php
  if(isset($_SESSION['users'])) { 
      $uname = $_SESSION['users']; 
      $fname = $_SESSION['firstname'];
      $lname = $_SESSION['lastname'];
      $dep = $_SESSION['depart'];
      $pos = $_SESSION['position'];
      $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = $uname");
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
          $id=$row['id'];
          $fname=$row['first_name']; 
          $lname=$row['last_name'];
          $dep = $row['department']; 
          $pos = $row['position']; 
          $repby = $row['first_name'] . " " . $row['last_name']; 
          $repdep = $row['department'];
          $reppos = $row['position'];
      } 
   } 
  mysqli_select_db($con, $db_name);
  $edit= "SELECT * FROM reports WHERE rep_id = '{$_GET['rep_id']}'";
  $result = mysqli_query($con, $edit) or die(mysqli_error($con));
  $row2 =  mysqli_fetch_array($result);

  if(isset($_POST['update'])) {
      $repid = $_POST['repid'];
      $reporttype = $_POST['reporttype'];
      $report = $_POST['report'];
      $repto = $_POST['reportedto'];
      $sql = "UPDATE reports SET rep_type='$reporttype', report='$report', rep_to='$repto', rep_ledit_date=NOW() WHERE rep_id='$repid'";
      $retval = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
      mysqli_close($con);
      $success="You have successfully edited your report.";
  }

  ?>
```

Then on the form, the values for reptype were not set. I also added a hidden field which retrieves the rep_id.

```
  <form name="editor" action="edit-this-report.php?rep_id=<?php echo $_GET['rep_id']; ?>" method="post" >
   <p class="inline">
    <span>
       <label for="mem">Reported by</label>
  <input type="text" name="reportedby" maxlength="20" disabled value="<?php print  $fname . " " . $lname; ?>" />
    </span>
   </p>
   <p class="inline">
     <span>
        <label for="mem">Department Name</label><input type="text" name="repdepart" disabled size="100" maxlength="100" value="<?php print $dep; ?>">
     </span>
   </p>
   <p class="inline">
      <span>
        <label for="mem">Position</label><input disabled type="text" name="repposition" size="100" value="<?php print $pos; ?>">
      </span>
   </p>
  <input name="repid" type="hidden" id="repid" value="<?php echo $row2['rep_id']; ?>">
   <p>
     <span>
     <select name="reporttype">
         <option value="Daily Report"<?php if ($row2['rep_type'] === 'Daily Report') echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>Daily Report</option>
         <option  value="Weekly Report"<?php if ($row2['rep_type'] === 'Weekly Report') echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>Weekly Report</option>
         <option value="Monthly Report"<?php if ($row2['rep_type'] === 'Monthly Report') echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>Monthly Report</option>
         <option value="Quarterly Report"<?php if ($row2['rep_type'] === 'Quarterly Report') echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>Quarterly Report</option>
         <option value="Annual Report"<?php if ($row2['rep_type'] === 'Annual Report') echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>Annual Report</option>
         <option  value="Terminal Report"<?php if ($row2['rep_type'] === 'Terminal Report') echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>Terminal Report</option>
     </select>
    <span>
   </p>

   <p>
    <span>
         <label for="mem">Report</label> 
         <textarea name="report" id="report" rows="23" cols="auto"><?php echo $row2['report'];?></textarea>
    <span>
   </p>
   <p>
    <span>
        <label for="mem">Reported to</label> 
        <select name="reportedto">
  <?php
  require ("includes/db.php");
        $q2= "SELECT * FROM users WHERE department like '%$repdep%'"; 
        $result3=mysqli_query($con, $q2) or die(mysqli_error($con));
        while ($getuser=mysqli_fetch_array($result3)){
        $repto=$getuser['first_name'] . " " . $getuser['last_name'];
  ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $repto; ?>"><?php echo $repto; ?></option>; 
        <?php       
        }       
        ?>

        </select>
    </span>
   </p>
    <span>
        <input name="update" type="submit" class="btn btn-large btn-primary" id="report_button" value="Submit Report" > 
        <input name="cancel" type="reset" class="btn btn-large btn-secondary" id="report_button" value="Cancel All Changes" >
    </span>
  </form>
   </p>
```

I hope this helps other visitors. Thank you bloodyKnuckles and Mark for the help!